# finding dual basis to trace map : is the computation correct?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\theta = \sqrt[3]2$ be the real cube root of $2$. While proving that the integral closure  $O$ of $\mathbb Q[\theta]$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Z[\theta]$, I was doing some computations, which I  would like to verify.

It is easy to see that $\mathbb Z[\theta] \subset O$. We have a lemma which states that if $\{x_i\}$  is a basis of $\mathbb Z[\theta]$ as a module over $\mathbb Q$, then $O$ is contained in $\mathbb Z[y_i]$, where $y_i$ is a dual basis to $x_i$, where $y_i \in \mathbb Q[\theta]$.

Now, I chose the basis $x_i = \{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$. With respect to this, the trace matrix $T_{ij} = \mbox{tr}(x_ix_j)$ should look like :
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $\theta,\theta^2$ have trace zero since their minimal polynomials are $x^3 - 2$ and $x^3 - 4$ respectively, whose next-to-leading coefficient is zero. Now, computing the dual basis is tantamount to finding the inverse of this matrix and taking the columns. Turns out the inverse of $T$ is just $\frac 14 T$.

Consequently, the dual basis is just the original basis scaled down by $4$.

This allows us to conclude that $4O \subset \mathbb Z[\theta]$.

All I would like to ask is : is the computation of the dual basis, and the resulting conclusion correct? The problem is, my printing material says $3
O \subset \mathbb Z[\theta]$(which is eventually correct) but this seems incorrect for now, in the light of my computation, since I was asked to conclude this using the dual basis argument.

Comment: The trace matrix is $$\pmatrix{3&0&0\\0&0&6\\0&6&0}.$$

Comment: Ignore previous comment. Clearly, $x_i = \sum_j \langle x_i,x_j\rangle  y_j$, so from here we get that $1 = 3 y_1$, $\theta =  6y_3$ and $\theta^2 = 6y_2$, so we get that $6O \subset \mathbb Z[\theta]$, but the $2$ will go off, since $2 \in \mathbb Z[\theta]$, so the result is clear.

Comment: In addition to having the wrong trace matrix something else is also a bit off. $\det T=-4$, so the inverse should have determinant $-1/4$. But $\det(T/4)=-1/16$.

Comment: I see the mistake, although with the corrected trace matrix this issue does not arise.